# Как правильно оформлять HTML код?

Tags: html, html5, оформление

Недавно начал разбираться в html разметке, и возникло несколько вопросов, касающихся ее оформления. Хотелось бы услышать мнение более опытных программистов.

1) Стоит ли отделять логические блоки пустой строкой? Одни говорят что это нужно делать,так как повышается понимание кода и удобочитаемость, другие - что это сильно увеличивает итоговый обьем кода,из-за чего нужно больше скроллить, и поэтому так делать не нужно.

2) Сколько использовать пробелов для отображения вложенности? Где-то написано 2,где-то 4.

3) Стоит ли переносить вообще все атрибуты в css,оставляя в html только класс или имя? К примеру ссылку в  стоит указывать в css?

Comment: Всё вкусовщина. // А ссылку как вы вообще собрались в css переносить? o_O

Comment: "К примеру ссылку в стоит указывать в css" - поясните смысл фразы.

Comment: Установи плагин для форматирования верстки и не парься....

Comment: @Air А что такие плагины поддерживает? Я сейчас в Notepad++ все делаю

Comment: Про Notepad++ не могу ничего сказать, я им пользовался минут 15... ))) А через 5 минут, как открыл для себя Sublime, я забыл про него... Но vsCode круче, а Sublime проще...  Все конечно дело вкуса...  И еще любопытно, как это понять - `"К примеру ссылку в стоит указывать в css"`

Comment: А подобный плагины поддерживают определенный формат кода, чтобы и глазу приятно и читалось легко...

Comment: @Air Я затупил тогда, думал что можно href указать в css. Сейчас уже понял что так нельзя) Спасибо за совет, как скачал Sublime про notepad++ сразу забыл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Лучше отделять и комментировать, особенно если только начинаешь. Скролл лишней строчки не самое страшное что может быть, читабельность в приоритете.
2) Каждый подбирает как удобно 2 или 4 пробела, в редакторе это можно настроить по параметру табуляции.
3) В css стоит переносить только стили. Сомневаюсь что у Вас получится перенести ссылку.